# How can I generate a cryptographically secure pseudo-random number in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cryptography

Is there a Cryptographically Secure Pseudo-Random Number Generator (CSPRNG) in Javascript?

I know I can generate a pseudo-random number using

`Math.random()`;

```
function getRandomInt(max) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}
```

In Python I would use `secrets()` instead of `random()`.

```
import secrets alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits password = ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(8))
```

In Go I would use the `crypto.rand` package instead of the `math/rand` package.

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "crypto/rand"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    c := 10
    b := make([]byte, c)
    _, err := rand.Read(b)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("error:", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(bytes.Equal(b, make([]byte, c)))

}
```

Is there an equivalent in javascript?

Comment: Are you working in the browser or node?

Comment: Let's say both. How can I do it in both?

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I didn't downvote. Probably someone came in and saw you didn't post a code sample?

Comment: didn't downvote either, but googling for "CSPRNG javascript" gives essentially the same information as you got here and would probably have been much quicker

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the browser, you can look into `window.crypto.getRandomValues`. See details [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues).

```
const array = new Uint32Array(10);
window.crypto.getRandomValues(array);
```

In node, take a peek at the [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).

```
const crypto = require('crypto');
crypto.randomBytes(20, (err, buffer) => {
  const token = buffer.toString('hex');
  console.log(token);
});
```

If you have browser support concerns, consider looking into an npm package like [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csprng). Note: I've never used this one so I can't vouch for it.

Comment: That package just uses the Node.js crypto module. [browserify](https://github.com/browserify/browserify/blob/master/readme.markdown#compatibility) would work.

Comment: However, the MDN says this:

"Don't use getRandomValues() to generate encryption keys. Instead, use the generateKey() method. There are a few reasons for this; for example, getRandomValues() is not guaranteed to be running in a secure context"...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/getRandomValues

Comment: ..."There is no minimum degree of entropy mandated by the Web Cryptography specification. User agents are instead urged to provide the best entropy they can when generating random numbers, using a well-defined, efficient pseudorandom number generator built into the user agent itself, but seeded with values taken from an external source of pseudorandom numbers, such as a platform-specific random number function, the Unix /dev/urandom device, or other source of random or pseudorandom data".